# Class term with Kuratowski pair

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As usual  $(x, y)$ is an abbreviation for $\left\{\{x\}, \{x,y\}\right\}$.
Given the class term:

$\left\{(x,y) \ |\  x\in A \wedge y\in A  \right\}$

for *every* $x$ is in $A$ and *every* $y$ in $A$ the $(x,y)$ pair belongs to the class.

I would like to build a class consisting of every $x$ in $A$ and only a given (single)  $y$ in $A$.
Is the following  the correct/best way?

$\left\{(x,y) \ |\  x\in A \wedge y=z \wedge z\in A  \right\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we write $\{u\mid\varphi(u)\}$ then $u$ is a free variable in $\varphi$. If you are given $y$, then $y$ is no longer a free variable, range over all possible values.

So it should be written as $\{(x,y)\mid x\in A\}$, and just make sure that the reader understands that $y$ is given and fixed.

What you wrote, $\{(x,y)\mid x\in A\land y=z\land z\in A\}$ is effectively just writing $\{(x,y)\mid x\in A\land y\in A\}$ again. So it's definitely not the right way.

Comment: Anyway I can only set $y$ properties outside the set definition. 
So in full it should be $\{(x,y)\mid x\in A\} \land y\in A$. 
I wonder if the properties of $y$ can be given inside the set definition and if this makes sense in general.

Comment: Amazing. I completely forgot about this answer, and it hasn't even been two weeks.